# Proving that the locus of the image of $(2, 3)$ in the line $2x-3y+4+k(x-2y+3) =0$ is a circle of radius $\sqrt2$.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Prove that the locus of the image of the point $(2, 3)$ in the line $2x-3y+4+k(x-2y+3) =0$, for $k$ real, is a circle of radius $\sqrt2$.

My approach was finding the equation of the line perpendicular to the given one and passing through (2, 3). After that finding out the point of intersection proved to be humongous for me. And that is where I got stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting anyone's time explaining things you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. Isolated problem statements tend to give the wrong impression, attracting down- and close-votes.) Edit your question to add details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Q(2,3)$

$P(h,k)$ be the required image

$M$ be the midpoint of $PQ$  i.e., $\left(\dfrac{h+2}2,\dfrac{k+3}2\right)$

The intersection of $2x-3y+4=0; x-2y+3=0$  is $R(1,2)$

Now  $MR\perp PQ$

$$\implies\dfrac{k-3}{h-2}\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{k+3}2-2}{\dfrac{h+2}2-1}=-1$$

$$\iff(h-1)^2+(k-2)^2=2$$

Answer (score 3):

For $k \in \Bbb{R}$, the line $L_1+kL_2=0$, represents the **family of lines** that pass through the intersection of the lines $L_1=0$ and $L_2=0$. The intersection point is $C(1,2)$.

In the picture below, let the given line be an arbitrary line that passes through the point $C(1,2)$. We reflect the given point $D(2,3)$ with respect to this line. Let $E(s,t)$ be the reflection of $D$. Then $DC=EC$. This means
$$(s-1)^2+(t-2)^2=(3-2)^2+(2-1)^2$$
[image]

So locus would be the circle with center at $(1,2)$ and radius equal to the distance between $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$

Comment: After reflecting (2, 3) with respect to (1, 2), the point of intersection, the image is just a point at (0, 1). Why is that the required locus would be a circle....?

Comment: @Mick I have further clarified what I meant by the statement and added details to the solution (earlier I just intended it as a hint).

Comment: +1 for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

P = $(2,3)$ Line L:   $(2x - 3y + 4) + k (x - 2y +3) = 0 $   $k ∈ R$

L passes through intersection point of  $2x-3y +4 =0$ and $x-2y+3 = 0$

Calculating point:  C$(1,2)$.

image points Q $(α, β)$ of P$(2,3$) wrt line L.

Shift Origin from O $(0,0)$ to C $(1,2)$ with new coordinate system of $X = x-1$ and $Y= y-2.$ We need to find the images of P$(X=2-1=1, Y=3-2=1)$ on lines passing thru C$(X=0, Y=0)$.

Clearly we can see that points $(X,Y)=(-1,-1), (-1, 1), (1,1), (1,-1)$ are image points wrt $X=-Y, X=0, X= Y, Y= 0$   respectively. Clearly the locus is a circle of radius = $CP = √(1²+1²) = √2$ Locus:   $$X² + Y² = 2$$  $$(x-1)² + (y-2)² = 2$$

Comment: Try to give hints first rather than posting complete solution. [Read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution).